# How can I get cookie value on server in Nuxt3?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

`/api/show.js`

```js
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const cookie = getCookie(event, 'jwt')

  console.log("cookie: " + cookie);
  
  return { cookie: cookie }
})
```

When I go to `http://localhost:3000/api/show` in my browser I can see the proper value on the screen and I can see the proper value logged to the console from the server.
But when I try to use it in my app, like this:

```html
<script setup>
const { data } = await useFetch('/api/show')
console.log(data.value.cookie);
</script>
```

then both console logs, the one on the server and the one on the client, show undefined.
What's the logic behind that?
How can I properly get cookie value on a server in Nuxt3?

Comment: Are you sure your browser has already any saved cookie in a browser? Does your component work only in browser, not in SSR? I'm not sure if SSR will `fetch` data using cookies you sent to him. Try to use `<client-only>` tag.

Comment: Yes, I'm 100% sure the cookie is set. I can even run setCookie() just before getCookie() and it's still undefined on server when called from app. I'm not sure how <client-only> html tag relates to it. Can you please explain?

Comment: Nuxt 3 works on server and on client using `<client-only>` tag you force component in it to run only on client side. Your `useFetch()` function in `<script setup>` will run twice on first page load.

Answer (score 7):

Due to breaking changes now you can't

- import `useCookie` from `#app`, `#imports` and `h3`.

Instead you should use `parseCookie` and `setCookie` imported from `h3`.

```js
import { defineEventHandler, H3Event, parseCookies, setCookie } from 'h3'
```

to get cookies

```js
export default defineEventHandler((event: H3Event) => {
  const cookies = parseCookies(event)
  const token = cookies?.token
```

to set cookies

```js
  setCookie(event, 'token', token)
```

Docs:
https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server

Answer (score 0):

You should use the useCookie composable for interfacing with cookies on both the client and server process.

See here:

https://nuxt.com/docs/examples/composables/use-cookie#usecookie

Comment: this is no solution in server side, firstly "Vue app aliases are not allowed in server routes.", secondly importing useCookie from "#imports" is too disallowed. Finally h3 changed api for cookie usage.

Comment: @Daniel useCookie is built into Nuxt3 and there is no need to import it.

Comment: on frontend part, but question is about server

Comment: @Daniel Perhaps I do not understand, but useCookie is SSR compatible and can be used also in the server lifecycle of Nuxt. Unless you are talking about a separate express server.

Comment: Strange. I had code with useCookie in server directory, but had to migrated it because it stops working. Check this issue: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/13965 in proposed solution they not longer using useCookie in server directory. I do not have to confirm it now, but if it is working for you we probably should add PR with clarification to nuxt docs.